# Can't open this picture because you don't have permission

Tags: php, file, permissions, mkdir

I have file uploading script and I have an if statement that checks if the file does not exists it will create one and upload file to it and if it exists it will upload the file to it.

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');

if (isset($_POST['do']) and $_POST['do'] == 'upload') {
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $date = "[".date("d-m-Y_H-i")."]";
    $temp = explode(".", $filename);
    $new_filename = $temp[0] . ""/*you can put any thing that you want before the [] in the 2 singels*/ . $date .'.' . end($temp);
    $f_folder = "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_filename;
    $username = $_POST['user'];

    //echo $username;
    if (!file_exists("uploads". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user'])){
    mkdir("uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST['user'],0777);
        if (empty($filename)) {
            echo "choose file please";
    }else {
           move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
           echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
    }
    }else if (empty($filename)) {
            echo "choose file please";
        }else {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
            echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
    };


};

echo "<hr>";
 echo "
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    File Path : <input type='file' name='file' />
    <br>
    Username : <input type='text' name='user' />
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name='do' value='upload' />
</form>";

?>
```

It works correctly but when I upload a photo, I can't open it. It gives me the following error:

> windows photo viewer can't open this picture because you don't have the
>   correct permissions to access the file location

-i have updated the code

Comment: Well, did you check the permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Use [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function of php to set permission after image upload.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists("uploads". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user'])){
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST['user'],777);
umask($oldmask);
    if (empty($filename)) {
        echo "choose file please";
}else {
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
       echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
}
}else if (empty($filename)) {
        echo "choose file please";
    }else {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
        echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
}
chmod($f_folder, 777); // add this line after image upload
```

Comment: do you mean something like this ? code : 
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
chmod($f_folder, 777);
echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
(that does not work

Comment: no `chmod($f_folder, 777);` write this code after your image is upload. Or you can use my code as it is

Comment: sorry i cant understand you can you give me the final code please ?

Comment: just paste this line `chmod($f_folder, 777);` after your code. as i use in my code